# Word UserForm VBA: Hyperlink from Bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am able to populate a bookmarked location on a Word Document from user input via a UserForm.

What I would like to do is convert the text entered into a Hyperlink.

The following snippit of code was used to insert the text into the appropriate location:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim benchmarkURL As Range
    Set benchmarkURL = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("benchmark").Range
    benchmarkURL.Text = Me.benchmarkURLTextBox.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "benchmark", benchmarkURL

    Me.Repaint

    'Update the fields to populate the references of the bookmarks
    UpdateAllFields

    UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

I tried the following which did not work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim benchmarkURL As Range
    Set benchmarkURL = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("benchmark").Range
    benchmarkURL.Text = Me.benchmarkURLTextBox.Value
    Hyperlinks.Add(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "benchmark", benchmarkURL)

    Me.Repaint

    'Update the fields to populate the references of the bookmarks
    UpdateAllFields

    UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Any advice will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Hyperlinks.Add(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "benchmark", benchmarkURL)
```

There are at least two things wrong with this line, possibly more depending on what it is you want the hyperlink to link to.

1. You have omitted the parent object for the Hyperlink which should be ActiveDocument.
2. There should not be any brackets as the return value of
   Hyperlinks.Add is not being assigned to anything.

You can find further info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837214(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution. For those that need, it is posted below:

```
'URL of Benchmark Data
Dim benchmarkURL As Range
Set benchmarkURL = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("benchmark").Range
benchmarkURL.Text = Me.benchmarkURLTextBox.Value
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=benchmarkURL, Address:= _
benchmarkURL.Text, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:= _
"Benchmark Data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide some further description to Jame's answer.

```
'URL of Benchmark Data
Dim benchmarkURL As Range
Set benchmarkURL = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("benchmark").Range
benchmarkURL.Text = Me.benchmarkURLTextBox.Value
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=benchmarkURL, Address:=benchmarkURL.Text, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="Benchmark Data"
```

means put this information in.

```
'URL of Benchmark Data
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=<<Where link will display>>, Address:= <<Where the link will go to>>, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="<<what the link     text should say"
```

This is my working version.  In my instance I take text like this AC-2 in a table cell and make a bookmark with AC2.  One table with AC-2 clicks to another table with AC-2 that is bookmarked.

```
'/////////////
Set benchmarkURL = oDoc.Bookmarks(strText2).Range
With oDoc.Tables(r).Cell(i, 1)
  .Range.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=oDoc.Tables(r).Cell(i, 1).Range, Address:="", SubAddress:=strText2, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=strText
End With
```